# Push Notification without APNS having secure Intranet

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For IOS App, we have secure intranet and want to send push notification without APNS.
I have gone through may scenarios on here on site. I am not able to find any answer if using our network and server is it possible to send push notification without APNS.

For Android App I found that it is possible to bypass GCMS. what about to bypass APNS for IOS?

Comment: You can use onesignal or FCM but FCM also sends push through APNs.

Comment: You cannot send push messages without using Apple's service. There is a trust relationship between Apple's servers and iOS which you cannot imitate as you don't have the required private keys.

Comment: APNS can only be done via Apples Push Notification sever, thus you need to use there servers. If you don't want this you will have to find some hacky way to keep your app open so that you can keep a socket going and implement your one push notification service. This will draining the battery of the uses phone. But can be done for none AppStore build.
Or you could use silent push notification with an encrypted message which your app decrypts thus no readable information is shared with the APNS server.

Comment: I'd suggest you to see into Local Notifications. In one of our projects it worked from a server-polling background service, but I was not the one who did it.

Answer (score 0):

APNS can not work in closed networks ! You need internet to reach publicly hosted Apple Cloud Server. It's not possible to by-pass Apple servers for any Push Notification to be delivered to your app.